# Disable SQL Server Login pop up for other users

Tags: sql-server, excel

Does anyone know how do I get rid of below popping up on other users computer who will only be using the spreadsheet as read-only file?

[image: SQL Server Login]

The data in the spreadsheet comes from a SQL query, and has OLE DB refresh enabled when opening the file. I will need to send this spreadsheet out to internal as well to external people but I don't want them to have this pop up appear on their screen.

The spreadsheet is collecting and updating data every time its opened and hence it is required to remain connected. What are my other options? There are more than 15 reports set up in the spreadsheet which will be sent out once every week internally as well externally.

I’m using the below VBA script to refresh the spreadsheet. Is there any code I could use in the script that will save the workbook and remove the SQL connection?

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

oExcel.Visible = True
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("file path.xlsx")
oWorkbook.RefreshAll
oWorkbook.Save

oExcel.Quit
Set oWorkbook = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: If the spreadsheet is collecting data every time it’s opened, a connection to the source will be necessary. If the source is the database, credentials will be needed. If credentials are needed, they must be provided. I can see two *common* business decisions here: (A) hard-code the account credentials into your Excel sheet (B) build an API that provides the necessary data to anyone with an access key. The second is better than the first, though management usually protests the whole time …

Comment: So that would be a function of your "program" - presumably Excel. TBH you probably want to strip your Excel file of all code and only send out the actual information. Your approach is how sensitive information can easily leak into the public.

Comment: This is probably a big “no”, but can you suggest to the company that you move away from a spreadsheet and give your internal and external people a password-protected, properly protected website? If the data is at all private or sensitive, then a spreadsheet is not the way to go. You *will* leak data.